# save all changes peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I am writting a lib and i am using peewee. Let's say that I have a class API and 2 models in peewee:

```
 class foo1(Model):
     id = PrimaryKeyField()
     bar = TextField(null=True)

 class foo2(Model):
     id = PrimaryKeyField()
     bar2 = TextField(null=True)

 class Api:
      def get_foo1_by_id(id) 
           return foo1.get(foo1.id == id)

      def get_foo2_by_id(id) 
           return foo2.get(foo1.id == id)

      def save_changes()
           ...
```

Now i do smth with foo1 & foo2 instances.

```
foo1 = Api.get_foo1_by_id(1)

foo2 = Api.get_foo2_by_id(1)

foo1.bar = 'str'

foo2.bar = 'str'
```

And now to save changes i have to write smth like

```
foo1.save()

foo2.save()
```

But i'd like to write a method inside my Api which will commit all changes of all models thats been changed. Is it possible?

Comment: You can create a set of the changed values and then iterate over the set at the end and call `save()`

Comment: I have to create a set inside my api? When the someone who use it retrive an object i add it inside set? Or you mean that the person who will use it have to do it himself

Comment: Oh I misunderstood, yeah it's not practical to expect the user of the API to maintain their own set, which is what i was suggesting